# How to set up HTTP outputs in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I've got a simple Azure function for which I set up a DocumentDB output (as an example):

[image: Azure Functions DocumentDB output screenshot]

I then added the `outputDocument` parameter to the function and assigned a value to it in the code (by the way I was surprised that when I set up the output that the runtime didn't automatically modify the function signature):

```
using System;

public static void Run(string input, out object outputDocument, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");

    outputDocument = new {
        text = $"I'm running in a C# function! {input}"
    };
}
```

When I run the function the Azure Functions runtime does it's binding magic and the DocumentDB document gets created.

I then set up an HTTP output:

[image: Azure Functions HTTP output]

and defined the `res` output parameter.

But now what?  What's the process of assigning to res?  I've of course got to define the destination, request type, parms, etc.

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter - thanks for continuing the SO tradition of downvoting with no comment as to why.  Gives me absolutely no feedback about how to improve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Howiecamp,

The HTTP output binding works in conjunction with the HTTP Trigger to act as the response handler for an HTTP request.

Currently, there isn't an output binding that would send the output payload over HTTP for you, so you'd need to make that HTTP request from your function code (e.g. using the `HttpClient` and issuing the request). You can see an example in one of our templates here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-templates/blob/10650dbf9c4bad75b0c89b9c355edc53fe913cde/Templates/GitHubCommenter-CSharp/run.csx#L40-L49

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks.  What's the purpose then of the HTTP output type that I can select from the list of outputs?  Obviously in the case of the DocumentDB output and others, the binding corresponds to an out param and handles the calling logic (eg DocDb doc creation).  Can I do anything with `res` (the default name of the http output var)?  Is the http output type just in the UI but not fully implemented yet?  (Kind of vestigial.)

Comment: That binding is a bit of a special case. As mentioned in the answer above, it works in conjunction with the HTTP trigger, in .Net languages, the value is assigned based on your function return type (HttpResponseMessage, POCO, string, etc.) in Node, for example, you can assign a response to the binding using its name. That's a response only binding. Currently, there's no HTTP request output binding that will bind to a function parameter.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for the explanation.  The key thing I understand now is that I should make the http request in my function code.

Comment: is this still the case? `there isn't an output binding that would send the output payload over HTTP for you` - or is this possible 2 years later now?

Comment: hello? is there still no http output binding without an http trigger?