# Azure function output API call to 3rd party service

Tags: c#, rest, api, azure, azure-functions

Hey all I'm still getting used to Azure functions a little bit and trying to figure out how we might apply them in our application. I've currently got a situation where I am using a Service Bus Queue Trigger function to activate whenever a message pops in the queue and I would then like to post a request to a 3rd party API when that message has been handled.

I understand that with Azure functions I can configure an output binding but is there anything already setup to execute a REST request on output? I'm currently assuming that we are going to have to include RestSharp and format the request ourselves within the function but is there an easier better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no HTTP output binding, which is what you are describing. Please take a look at the available output bindings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings

The way to accomplish a call to a third-party once your function is triggered, is exactly as you described it: Making an HTTP call yourself.

In fact, here is an answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39187578/84395

Comment: Thanks so much this is what I was looking for. Are you aware if this is something that is in the pipeline for Azure Functions or it is just expected that you will have to make the HTTP call yourself?

Comment: In the refered documentation from microsoft the output binding inferred by the return type ...

make the function return type HttpResponseMessage or Task<HttpResponseMessage>. In C#, a return value attribute isn't required.