# How to use Azure Function as endpoint for IoTHub

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have connected a Function App to an IoTHub and it triggers on the incoming events. The messages show as expected in the log window.
How can I direct the messages to an http endpoint as a REST interface?

Comment: Please refer to this existing one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839499/azure-function-output-api-call-to-3rd-party-service

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to this blog post: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-use-azure-functions-with-iot-hub-message-routing/